# Automatically import custom files in Django

Tags: python, django, import

I have a Django project containing some files which are, obviously, not automatically discovered by Django. My workaround is to import them in `urls.py` so that Django can see them. This is how my `urls.py` looks like:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from custom_file_1 import *  # "unused" import
from custom_file_2 import *  # "unused" import

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]
```

My IDE considers the commented imports unused, since they are not used, but they are vital so that Django can process those files.

And the question: is there any nice way to let Django see those files? And how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually *not* a good idea to import things with wildcards. Imagine that in one of the custom files some object with the name `path` is present, then it will override the reference to the `path` function you imported from `django.urls`.

Usually one imports such files (that for example contain signals, etc.) in the `AppConfig`.

In the directory of the app, there is an `__init__.py` file. You can write

```
# app/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'app.config.CustomAppConfig'
```

In your app directory, you then define the config of your app:

```
# app/config.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class CustomAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app'

    def ready(self):
        import custom_file_1  # noqa
        import custom_file_2  # noqa
```

Here [**`# noqa`**](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html#in-line-ignoring-errors) is used to ignore the flake8 warnings.

Comment: The files are not a part of any Django app, but it should not be a problem to make an app for them. However, it would then be the programmer's responsibility to add all the files manually into the config, which is pretty much the same as importing them (speaking of the amount of written code by the programmer). Wouldn't it be possible to somehow autodiscover them, maybe some magic with `importlib`?